# Ruby on Rails - order by updated_at by ignoring seconds and milliseconds

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

Want to display all Users order by updated_at column.
But I should ignore seconds and milliseconds.

Using Postgres database.
Currently updated_at is having values like "2014-09-08 12:59:32.61052"

Have many records with same updated_at value with some difference in seconds and milliseconds.

I have to ignore seconds and milliseconds while fetching and displaying the data.

How can I do that ?

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to use `date_trunc()` function

```
User.order("date_trunc('minute', updated_at)")
```

Have a look at documentation for [date_trunc()](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-TRUNC)